# I don't understand this example in Lua

Tags: lua

```
function maximum (a)
  local mi = 1          -- maximum index
  local m = a[mi]       -- maximum value
  for i,val in ipairs(a) do
    if val > m then
      mi = i
      m = val
    end
  end
  return m, mi
end

print(maximum({8,10,23,12,5}))--> 23   3
```

I can't understand this, would someone explain this example? It's so confusing, **Programming in Lua First edition** always make some hard examples.

Comment: Can you please be more specific. What parts of the code do you have problems with? What parts do you understand? And the parts you have problems with, what do you *think* they could mean or do?

Comment: >everything about this code ;-; i think *a* is a parameter but also a table so we can use *a[mi]*. But what are the values inside this table?and we put 5 values, why does ***Lua*** only returns 2 values?I know the last line is return m, mi but i tried to remove some values, the result isn't 23 3 anymore. Did it plus something? I don't see any "+". And this should be ">=" not ">", but Lua doesn't say anything about the error when i was running this code. I thought *m* ==  *val^? How *m*  > *val*?? *m*  **IS**  *val*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function takes one argument, which is a table that is stored in the variable `a`.

The function iterates (loops) over each value in the table `a`, using the `ipairs` function to return the index and value from the table (temporarily stored in `i` and `val`).

Inside the loop the value from the table is compared against `m`, and if `val` is larger than `m` then `m` is assigned the value of `val` and `mi` is assigned the value of `i`.

Then the function returns the two values `m` and `mi`.

In short what the function does, is to find the maximum values and its index in the table passed as the argument.

Comment: your answer is good, but still, why *if val > m then* but not *if val => m then* ?

Comment: @BlaztOne The function finds the *largest* value in the table, not which one is larger or equal to the other values.

Comment: @BlaztOne Or think of it as a preference - find the first element that is equal to maximum, and not the last one. Apparently the author didn't mean to illustrate the cases when there's multiple values equal to max, so `>` isn't any better or worse than `>=`. Whether it matters or not - depends on your task, and it's beyond this short sample.